# Connecting client to server Kryonet and Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, network-programming, kryonet

I'm trying to connect from a client which uses libgdx for the interface to a server. I use Kryonet on both the client and the server. However it is not working. Any idea what's wrong?

Here is the code that i use in the client:

```
     Client client = new Client();
        Kryo kryo = client.getKryo();
        kryo.register(String.class);
        client.start();
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    client.connect(5000, "localhost", 54555, 54777);
                    client.addListener(new Listener() {
                        public void received(Connection connection, Object object) {
                            if (object instanceof String) {
                                String response = (String) object;
                                System.out.println(response);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.warn("expection", e);
                }
            }
        }.start();
   client.sendTCP("Hey There");
```

Here is the server code:

```
Server server = new Server();
    Kryo kryo = server.getKryo();
            kryo.register(String.class);
            server.start();
            try {
                server.bind(54555, 54777);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            server.addListener(new Listener() {
                public void received (Connection connection, Object object) {
                   if (object instanceof String) {
                      String request = (String)object;
                      System.out.println("Server"+request);

                      String response = "Login succes";
                      connection.sendTCP(response);
                   }
                }
             });
```

Here is the error that i get:

```
[kryonet] Error updating connection.
com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoNetException: Incorrect number of bytes (1 remaining) used to deserialize object: null
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.TcpConnection.readObject(TcpConnection.java:146)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.update(Client.java:255)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.run(Client.java:338)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Client" com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoNetException: Incorrect number of bytes (1 remaining) used to deserialize object: null
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.TcpConnection.readObject(TcpConnection.java:146)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.update(Client.java:255)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.run(Client.java:338)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
00:05  WARN: expection
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connected, but timed out during TCP registration.
Note: Client#update must be called in a separate thread during connect.
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.connect(Client.java:168)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.connect(Client.java:117)
    at me.fort.historywars.LoginScreen$1.run(LoginScreen.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I consider this code fixed:

Server:

```
server = new Server();
    Kryo kryo = server.getKryo();
    kryo.register(SRq.class);
    server.start();
    try {
        server.bind(54555, 54777);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to bind to port!");
    }
    server.addListener(new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void received(Connection connection, Object object) {
            if(object instanceof SRq) {
                System.out.println("Server " +  ((SRq) object).data);
                SRq sRq = new SRq();
                sRq.data = "Data";
                connection.sendTCP(sRq);
            }
        }
    });
```

Client:

```
client = new Client();
    Kryo kryo = client.getKryo();
    kryo.register(SRq.class);
    client.start();
    try {
        client.connect(6000, "localhost", 54555, 54777);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to connect to server!");
    }
    client.addListener(new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void received(Connection connection, Object object) {
            if(object instanceof SRq) {
                Gdx.app.log("Client", ((SRq) object).data);
            }
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Connected to server!");

    SRq sRq = new SRq();
    sRq.data = "Log in";
    client.sendTCP(sRq);
```

Things to keep in mind:

- `SRq.class` is just a class with a public `String` inside it
- Make sure you use the same KryoNet version in both your Client and Server. I used `kryonet-2.21-all`. Download the jars, make a folder called `libs` in your core folder, put the jar inside it, and add this to your `build.gradle` (in core dependencies): `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested, but i get the same error. Also, i checked for `null` but I'm not sending a `null` String. It works if i try to connect from a client that is not part of a Libgdx app though. I only get the error when the client is inside Libgdx.

Comment: @Andy are you connecting from Desktop or Android?

Comment: I'm trying to connect from Desktop

Comment: By the way, if i start the server in the same app as the client, then the connection is succesful, However, i want the server to be in a separate application.

Comment: Thanks! It works. The problem was that I had another version of KryoNet specified in the `build.gradle` file. By the way, do you know if I have to create a thread for each client that connects to the server? Or does KryoNet handle that by itself?

Comment: @Andy In your client application one client is enough, you don't need to create multiple ones. When working with Android, set up the Client in a new Thread, and use Client#sndTcp() in a new Thread.